# CSS selector to target rows in grid

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

I have been working on an expandable card that has a dynamic number of rows and columns depending on the content length and width of the container. I want the card to first be in collapsed view where only the first row is displayed and expand to show the full card when the user toggles the card. I am wondering if there is an option to hide all rows except the first one using CSS based on conditional class added on button toggle if not what would be the ideal solution to handle this using javascript? bear in mind the number of columns in a row will change based on screen size.

[sample code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-wescoff-07vbj)

Comment: you can use psuedo classes `:first-child` and `nth-child`

Comment: yes but if your using css only you might need to use "target" as well and adjacent selectors "~". I'm trying a solution right now

Comment: basically u want something like a show more read less on this website with only using css https://54x1.github.io/churchill/ is that it?